# How to implement a catch all route with java spark for an SPA

Tags: java, html, single-page-application

The app I'm trying to get working uses Vue.js and Java Spark. I am trying to get the SPA to work with HTML5 history mode. Right now it serves the index page and the app takes over routing from there. Because of html5 routing, if I try to go straight to a url such as "/about", i'll get an error. I tried to add a catch all route using:

```
get("/*", (rq, rs) -> new ModelAndView(map, "index.hbs"), new HandlebarsTemplateEngine());
```

But this overrides the previously defined static file routing in:

```
staticFileLocation("/public");
```

How can I implement a catch all route for all other pages without overriding the static file routes? I'd rather not have to redefine every route on the server to the same page. I've accomplished this in node.js with express, It has to be possible with Spark.

Answer (score 0):

```
Spark.get("*", (request, response) ->
{
     response.type("application/json");
     return "not supported";
});
```

Should do the trick.